# Python: CGI program wants to know the IP address of the calling web page

Tags: php, python, header, cgi

I am new to Python programming.

I am stuck on what should be a simple procedure.  I have a small and basic Python program that is called as CGI program by a web page.

All that I want to do is extract the IP address from the HTTP header fields.
For example, in PHP, this would be the value of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

I paid my dues by doing a search, and I came up with the fact that I need to use web.ctx.ip, but when I use that bit in code, there is an exception.  I probably need to import something.  I've tried the following individual imports without success:

```
import web
import webapi as web
```

I'd appreciate a **complete** snippet of code that demonstrates what I need to import.  My Python CGI program is running on a Linux box that has a basic Python version 2.4.3 installed.  Do I need to install something else?

Comment: Look at the your request object or equivalent; try to find the `REMOTE_ADDR` field.

Comment: It also depends on how you are running Python. Are you using WSGI?

Comment: He's using CGI, as he says in the question.

Comment: @george only a duplicate if he's using web.py.

Comment: No, I'm not using WSGI, nor am am I using web.py.  Just generic code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1840):

```
# When run as a cgi script, this will print the client's IP address.

import html
import os

print("Content-type: text/html")
print("")

print html.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])
```

The search was for "python cgi get ip address" and it was the first result. This answer is for generic Python CGI, if you're using some other interface / library then it might be different. It is the exact analog of the PHP version, however, as you can see.

Comment: This is exactly what the doctor ordered.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The example above worked great for me. I added a little extra for local testing. I had to search for a long time to find this example so "thank you!"

```
import cgi
import os

def f_get_ipaddress():
    try:
        ipaddress = cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"])
    except:
        ipaddress = "127.0.0.1"

    return ipaddress

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""

ipaddress = f_get_ipaddress()

print ipaddress
```